# Can't install Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise:Stuck in installation loop

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, hyper-v

Basically after I add the role in the server manager and restart for the first time, the progress bar fills and after that I'm informed that installation failed and that computer is reverting the process. After that it reboots by itself and one progress bar later I can log in. After that I'm taken back to the server manager which shows me the exact same screen which I had before the restart.

After several cycles, the server manager won't start and I can leave the loop, but that doesn't solve my problem with Hyper-V installation.

And if it matters, yes I have hardware support for virtualization and it works fine in other virtual machines.

Comment: Do the Event Logs report any warnings or errors?  How about any messages or errors codes reported by the Server Manager when it tells you it failed?

Comment: @techie007  I get `Update Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients of package Microsoft-Hyper-V-Management-Clients-Package failed to be turned on. Status: 0x80004005.` and `Update Microsoft-Hyper-V of package Microsoft-Hyper-V-Package failed to be turned on. Status: 0x80004005.` as information in event log. Server Manager shows no errors (and reports installation success in event log). During start, there is no error message number.

Comment: If you hadn't figured it out already: 0x80004005 is a Access Denied error.  Are you running any other virtualization software on that server?

Comment: @techie007 No. It's a clean install with just the drivers.

Comment: Interesting. :)  If it's clean with just drivers: Have you ensured all drivers are installed and up-to-date?  Have you retried the OS install from scratch?  Have you done disk and file-system checks?  Can you clarify what "it works fine in other virtual machines" means?  What 'other virtual machines'?  This 2008 R2 is a _host_ OS right? :)

Comment: @techie007  Related thread [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/0e8703f4-3991-4efe-8cce-0e41a18d4857/). I don't have the 100 meg system partition here on this setup and I'm not sure I could easily add it. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @techie007 I have 3 other OSes installed on other drives on this computer and virtual machines on them run fine (even those that need hardware virtualization). All drivers are newest and disk an filesystem are fine. I tried reinstalling the win 2008 and it didn't help, but read my previous comment. Since I already have a partition table, I don't know how to make windows make the 100 MB partition (I could remove one of the GNU/Linux swap partitions to make room).

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with it. The infamous "100MB partition" is usually for BitLocker.  Does [MS' VM detection tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=592) say your system is VT enabled (in the 2008 host you rare trying to enable Hyper-V in)?

Comment: @techie007 That tool doesn't work in 2008. I'll have to restart and get back to you in a few minutes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2275/discussion-between-techie007-and-andrejako)

Comment: Also I tried `DISM /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName: Microsoft-Hyper-V` from that other thread and got:`
Error: 87

The /FeatureName: option is missing a required argument. 
For more information, refer to the help for the /FeatureName: option.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
`

Comment: @techie007 Also I'm having problems logging into chat.

Comment: If you suspect odd partitions can cause the trouble, perhaps try dismounting all the other drives in 2008 and then installing Hyper-V? And/Or perhaps fire up Process Monitor and try to determine what call is triggering the Access Denied?

 
Also, perhaps try running the [2008 R2 Readiness Tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821) - It will take a while but can point-out/correct many issues.

Comment: @techie007 I'm running the readiness tool now. How would I use the process monitor? The problematic part seems to happen before I get user interface.

Comment: [How To Enable System Boot Time Logging using Process Monitor Tool](http://www.msigeek.com/6231/how-to-enable-system-boot-time-logging-using-process-monitor-tool)

Answer (score 2):

The article [Installing Hyper-V on Windows Server 2008 R2](http://www.petri.co.il/installing-hyper-v-on-windows-server-2008-r2.htm) details two more methods for installing it, besides via the GUI :

**Using the Command Prompt**

Open a Command Prompt window with elevated permissions and enter either of :

```
servermanagercmd -i Hyper-V
servermanagercmd -i Hyper-V -restart
```

**Using PowerShell**

Open a PowerShell window and type :

```
Import-Module servermanager
```

then either of:

```
Add-WindowsFeature Hyper-V
Add-WindowsFeature Hyper-V -restart
```

If neither of these methods works, then my only suggestion is to clean-install Server 2008
and try again.

If it still does not work, then your motherboard is maybe unsuitable
to support Hyper-V.